# JavaScript two arrays merge into new Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two sets of arrays data, one for orders and one for picking orders. The order id of those arrays is the same. Data for picking orders is nested arrays. There is one value named `orderHasAlcohol` in the `Picking` orders data. I'd like to make a new array in which I can add `orderHasAlcohol` from the `Orders` data.

I am not sure how I can do it.

```js
const ordersData = [
  {
    additionalInfo: null,
    comment: null,
    deliveryDate: "2022-07-14",
    deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",
    deliveryTime: "10-12",
    discountCode: null,
    id: "1234", // orderId
    orderStatus: "NEW",
    paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
    paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",
    storeId: "12345",
  },
  {
    additionalInfo: null,
    comment: null,
    deliveryDate: "2022-07-23",
    deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",
    deliveryTime: "10-12",
    discountCode: null,
    id: "123", // orderId
    orderStatus: "NEW",
    paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
    paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",
    storeId: "12345",
  },
  {
    additionalInfo: null,
    comment: null,
    deliveryDate: "2022-07-23",
    deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",
    deliveryTime: "10-12",
    discountCode: null,
    id: "198", // orderId
    orderStatus: "NEW",
    paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
    paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",
    storeId: "12345",
  },

  {
    additionalInfo: null,
    comment: null,
    deliveryDate: "2022-07-23",
    deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",
    deliveryTime: "10-12",
    discountCode: null,
    id: "125", // orderId
    orderStatus: "NEW",
    paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
    paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",
    storeId: "12345",
  },
];
```

---

```
const pickingOrder = {
  ordersPickedAndDone: {
    orderCount: 0,
    rows: [],
  },
  ordersPickedAndPaid: {
    orderCount: 0,
    rows: [],
  },
  ordersPickedCanStart: {
    orderCount: 2,
    rows: [
      {
        orderHasAlcohol: false,
        orderId: "123",
      },
      {
        orderHasAlcohol: true,
        orderId: "198",
      },
    ],
  },
  ordersPickingProgress: {
    orderCount: 2,
    rows: [
      {
        pickingRun: 1,
        partitions: [
          {
            orderHasAlcohol: false,
            orderId: "125",
          },
          {
            orderHasAlcohol: true,
            orderId: "1234",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

---

```
// This is my expected arrays output

const expectedArrays = [
  {
    additionalInfo: null,
    comment: null,
    deliveryDate: "2022-07-14",
    deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",
    deliveryTime: "10-12",
    discountCode: null,
    id: "1234", // orderId
    orderStatus: "NEW",
    paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
    paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",
    storeId: "12345",
    orderHasAlcohol: true,
  },

  {
    additionalInfo: null,
    comment: null,
    deliveryDate: "2022-07-23",
    deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",
    deliveryTime: "10-12",
    discountCode: null,
    id: "123", // orderId
    orderStatus: "NEW",
    paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
    paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",
    storeId: "12345",
    orderHasAlcohol: false,
  },
  {
    additionalInfo: null,
    comment: null,
    deliveryDate: "2022-07-23",
    deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",
    deliveryTime: "10-12",
    discountCode: null,
    id: "198", // orderId
    orderStatus: "NEW",
    paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
    paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",
    storeId: "12345",
    orderHasAlcohol: true,
  },

  {
    additionalInfo: null,
    comment: null,
    deliveryDate: "2022-07-23",
    deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",
    deliveryTime: "10-12",
    discountCode: null,
    id: "125", // orderId
    orderStatus: "NEW",
    paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
    paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",
    storeId: "12345",
    orderHasAlcohol: false,
  },
];

console.log({expectedArrays});
```

P.S.: I am using [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) for my function validation. it would be nice to create new array by using ramda. but not necessary.

Comment: [Rambda](https://selfrefactor.github.io/rambda/#/) and [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) are two different libraries.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+merge+nested+object+arrays+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Ramda but with native js it should looks like this :

First you simplify `expectedArrays` to get an `array` of `object` which associate the `orderId` to the property `orderHasAlcohol` :

```
let pickingOrderSimplified = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(pickingOrder).map(key => {
    return  pickingOrder[key].rows.length > 0 && pickingOrder[key].rows.at(0).partitions ?  
            pickingOrder[key].rows.map(row => row.partitions).flat() : 
            pickingOrder[key].rows;
}).flat().map(el => [el.orderId, el.orderHasAlcohol]));
```

Then you can merge arrays :

```
let res = ordersData.map(data => ({
    ...data,
    orderHasAlcohol: pickingOrderSimplified[data.id]
}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @Krisna if you need any explanation about a specific part of the code, you can ask me ;)

Comment: Thank you for  your answer. I liked you answer really lot. Currently, I am having one typescript issue. I fetching the datas from Graphql then I combine to new arrays which you helped me. There is two issues I am facing,  one from `pickingOrderSimplified` last value return `undefined: undefined` and here is the another issue: https://codeshare.io/Od8N3r

Comment: I'm glad my answer heplped you, unfortunatly I'm not aware with typescript but it's looks like you have to define `row`, `rows` and their elements types. For the other issu can you share the result you have ? I don't have any `undefined` : `undefined`but maybe this is becose you use a different set of data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```js
let alcoholContentMap = {};
for (const key of Object.keys(pickingOrder)) {
  const orderCount = pickingOrder[key].orderCount;
  if (orderCount > 0) {
    for (const index = 0; index < orderCount; index++) {
      const currentOrder = pickingOrder[key].rows[index];

      if ('partitions' in currentOrder) {
        for (const partition of currentOrder)
          alcoholContentMap[partition.orderId] = partition.orderHasAlcohol;
      } else {
          alcoholContentMap[currentOrder.orderId] = partition.orderHasAlcohol;
      }
    }
  }
}
const expectedArrays = ordersData.map(order => {
  if (order.orderId in alcoholContentMap) {
    return {
      ...order,
      orderHasAlcohol: alcoholContentMap[order.orderId]
    }
  } else return order;
});
```

If you read this code, you'll see that the first part retrieves the information needed from `pickingOrder` and the second one applies it to your array. If it is in your hands, I would suggest simplifying the structure of the `pickingOrder` array in order to optimize the reading process, but anyways, this should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a generator that yields the objects of interest from the picking order object.

I would also key the main data by id, so you can quickly find an object by id and merge more data into it.

```js
const ordersData = [{additionalInfo: null,comment: null,deliveryDate: "2022-07-14",deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",deliveryTime: "10-12",discountCode: null,id: "1234",orderStatus: "NEW",paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",storeId: "12345",},{additionalInfo: null,comment: null,deliveryDate: "2022-07-23",deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",deliveryTime: "10-12",discountCode: null,id: "123",orderStatus: "NEW",paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",storeId: "12345",},{additionalInfo: null,comment: null,deliveryDate: "2022-07-23",deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",deliveryTime: "10-12",discountCode: null,id: "198",orderStatus: "NEW",paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",storeId: "12345",},{additionalInfo: null,comment: null,deliveryDate: "2022-07-23",deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",deliveryTime: "10-12",discountCode: null,id: "125",orderStatus: "NEW",paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",storeId: "12345",},];

const pickingOrder = {ordersPickedAndDone: {orderCount: 0,rows: [],},ordersPickedAndPaid: {orderCount: 0,rows: [],},ordersPickedCanStart: {orderCount: 2,rows: [{orderHasAlcohol: false,orderId: "123",},{orderHasAlcohol: true,orderId: "198",},],},ordersPickingProgress: {orderCount: 2,rows: [{pickingRun: 1,partitions: [{orderHasAlcohol: false,orderId: "125",},{orderHasAlcohol: true,orderId: "1234",},],},],},};

// Yield objects from given data structure that have "orderId" property
function* iterOrderInfo(obj) {
    if (Object(obj) !== obj) return;
    if (obj.orderId) yield obj;
    for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
        yield* iterOrderInfo(value);
    }
}

// Key the main data by order id
const map = new Map(ordersData.map(obj => [obj.id, {...obj}]));

// Associate objects retrieved from picking order by id and merge them into the data
for (const {orderId, ...rest} of iterOrderInfo(pickingOrder)) {
    Object.assign(map.get(orderId), rest);
}

// Retrieve the results 
const result = [...map.values()];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pragmatic solution

```js
const re = /"orderHasAlcohol":(true|false),"orderId":("\d+")/g;
let alco = [...JSON.stringify(pickingOrder).matchAll(re)]
  .reduce((acc, entry) => {
    const key = entry[2].replaceAll('\"', ""); /// this could be more elegant
    acc[key] = entry[1] === "true";
    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(alco)

ordersData.forEach(order => order.hasAlcohol = alco[order.id] ? ? false)
console.log(ordersData)
```

```html
<script>
  const ordersData = [{
      additionalInfo: null,
      comment: null,
      deliveryDate: "2022-07-14",
      deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",
      deliveryTime: "10-12",
      discountCode: null,
      id: "1234", // orderId
      orderStatus: "NEW",
      paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
      paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",
      storeId: "12345",
    },
    {
      additionalInfo: null,
      comment: null,
      deliveryDate: "2022-07-23",
      deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",
      deliveryTime: "10-12",
      discountCode: null,
      id: "123", // orderId
      orderStatus: "NEW",
      paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
      paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",
      storeId: "12345",
    },
    {
      additionalInfo: null,
      comment: null,
      deliveryDate: "2022-07-23",
      deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",
      deliveryTime: "10-12",
      discountCode: null,
      id: "198", // orderId
      orderStatus: "NEW",
      paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
      paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",
      storeId: "12345",
    },

    {
      additionalInfo: null,
      comment: null,
      deliveryDate: "2022-07-23",
      deliveryMethod: "PICKUP",
      deliveryTime: "10-12",
      discountCode: null,
      id: "125", // orderId
      orderStatus: "NEW",
      paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
      paymentStatus: "UNAVAILABLE",
      storeId: "12345",
    },
  ];

  const pickingOrder = {
    ordersPickedAndDone: {
      orderCount: 0,
      rows: [],
    },
    ordersPickedAndPaid: {
      orderCount: 0,
      rows: [],
    },
    ordersPickedCanStart: {
      orderCount: 2,
      rows: [{
          orderHasAlcohol: false,
          orderId: "123",
        },
        {
          orderHasAlcohol: true,
          orderId: "198",
        },
      ],
    },
    ordersPickingProgress: {
      orderCount: 2,
      rows: [{
        pickingRun: 1,
        partitions: [{
            orderHasAlcohol: false,
            orderId: "125",
          },
          {
            orderHasAlcohol: true,
            orderId: "1234",
          },
        ],
      }, ],
    },
  };
</script>
```